# DELETE from Table Where Column exists and equal OR DO Nothing if column not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

How to rewrite next script:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('TBL_Resources','ResourceType') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    delete
    from TBL_Resources
    where ResourceType like '%PpeSet%'
       or ResourceType like '%PpeUtilizationNorm%'
END
```

This script isn't working, when `ResourceType` doesn't exist. Is there any other way to handle it?

In case when I try to use not existing table for some delete query with check if table exists, everything is fine:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('aspnet_Roles', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
   delete
   from aspnet_Roles
   where LoweredRoleName like '%Ppe%'
END
```

Comment: Why might your table not have the column would be my question; why is the definition of the table in question?

Comment: @Larnu, I have bunch of scripts that I run on some db. I would like to apply all this scripts again on db (that might be already with this updates or not). As this bunch may be updated with new scripts, I would like just to run all previous scripts again

Comment: So the databases might not be up to date? Why not bring them "up to speed" first?

Comment: @Larnu, to do some step-by-step refactoring...

Comment: To answer the problem, you'll need to use deferred statements here. SQL is a compiled language, and for some objects something not existing will result in a compilation error; referencing a column that *doesn't* exist in a table that *does* is one such scenario that will cause a compilation error (referencing a column in a table that doesn't exist does not).