# Unexpected DB error from False If/Then/Else condition

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, alter

I'm checking for the existence of a column. The first time the query is executed, the column shouldn't be there and the query will add that column. If I happen to run the query a second time, the column should already be there and I just want to re-initialize its values. A DB error is being thrown when I run it the first time, it's telling me the Update statement is accessing a non-existing column and it errors out. How do I get around this chicken and egg situation?

```
IF COL_LENGTH('MonthlySummary', 'Total_Amt_14') IS NULL
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE MonthlySummary 
        ADD Total_Amt_14 MONEY DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL,  
            Transactions_14 INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    UPDATE MonthlySummary 
    SET Total_Amt_14 = 0.0, 
        Transactions_14 = 0
END
```

I can remove the ELSE condition, issue the query, and then always run the UPDATE query but it's not as efficient as having the ELSE in there.

Comment: Run the UPDATE inside dynamic SQL. This should avoid the problem

Comment: The column name is validated before the batch executes, resulting in a compilation error the first time.

Comment: You need *deferred compilation*.

Comment: I'm pretty confident I saw this post yesterday... (Nope, it was just a *very* [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321863/delete-from-table-where-column-exists-and-equal-or-do-nothing-if-column-not-exis) question, with identical problems and syntax).

Comment: The guy who can explain how SQL Server chooses to either crash or succeed in various deferred scenarios will get all my marbles